# Connect Dialogflow with Google BigQuery via Cloudfunctions with Python

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-firestore, connection, google-cloud-functions

I'm new on Python and cloud functions but I saw that it's possible to connect Dialogflow and GoogleBigQuery via Cloudfunctions but I do not understand how to make this, can someone explain me how to do it or if the way I'm trying to it's at least close?

```
import flask
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import make_response

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/prueba_1', methods=['POST'])
def prueba_1():
    import json
    import pandas as pd
    ss = pd.read_gbq("SELECT something FROM bigquery_table LIMIT 1","arbor-209819")
    ll = {
        "speech" : ss.to_json(),
        "displayText": ss.to_json(),
        "source": "apiai-weather-webhook-sample"
    }
    res = json.dumps(ll, indent=4)
    r = make_response(res)
    r.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    return r

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi Jeffer, thank you for your question. Are you getting any error when trying to run your code? If not can you be more specific what are you trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You are close, your function needs to accept the request. Also, python for cloud functions removes a lot of the overhead out of the code (you will still need it for local testing though). You can follow [this](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-python#top_of_page) quickstart to get you started.

Here is an example of how it could be written:

```py
from flask import jsonify
import pandas as pd

def prueba_1(request):

    # Your code

    ss = pd.read_gbq('SELECT * FROM my_dataset.my_table')

    # More code

    return jsonify(my_dictionary)
```

[jsonify](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.json.jsonify) takes a dict object and returns an application/json Response. Remember to add pandas and pandas-gbq in your requirements.

Finally, if you are using cloud functions to set up a [custom webhook](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-configure#custom_webhook) for Dialogflow, remember to check the [request](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-how#request_format) and [response](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-how#response_format) formats.